# extract value from a set in python

Tags: python-2.7, set

here is the output in sql query output in set format in python. how to extract just the value to a variable 
ResultSet({'(u'tx', None)': [{u'value': 31399946096.0, u'time': u'2016-10-05T05:06:15.009545466Z'}]})

i need v=31399946096.0

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried this way to get it the value out:

```
result=({'(u'tx', None)': [{u'value': 31399946096.0, u'time': u'2016-10-05T05:06:15.009545466Z'}]})

r=list(result)  
for i in r:  
    print i[0]['value']
```

which yields `31399946096.0`.
Is there any other way?